# Performing arithmetic with a multi-index pandas dataframe that needs broadcasting at several levels

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   one                     two                    three                   
     1         2             1             2          1             2     
     X    Y    X    Y        X    Y        X    Y     X        Y    X    Y
a  0.3 -0.6 -0.3 -0.2  1.5e+00  0.3 -1.0e+00  1.2   0.6 -9.8e-02 -0.4  0.4
b -0.6 -0.4 -1.1  2.3 -7.4e-02  0.7 -7.4e-02 -0.5  -0.3 -6.8e-01  1.1 -0.1
```

How do I divide all elements of `df` by `df["three"]` ?

I tried `df.div(df["three"],level=[1,2])` with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a one liner.

```
df / pd.concat( [ df.three ] * 3, axis=1 ).values
```

And here's another way that is a little less concise but may be more readable.

```
df2 = df.copy()
for c in df.columns.levels[0]:
    df2[c] = df[c] / df['three']
```

And finally, here is a longer solution with more of an explanation.  I did it this way originally before realizing there were better ways.  But I'll keep it here as it is more informative about what is happening behind the scenes on an operation like this (though possibly overkill).

First off, multi-index doesn't copy well, so I'll create a sample dataframe that is pretty similar.

```
np.random.seed(123)
tuples = list(zip(*[['one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'three', 'three'],
                    ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar']]))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 6), index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=index)

first        one                 two               three          
second       foo       bar       foo       bar       foo       bar
A      -1.085631  0.997345  0.282978 -1.506295 -0.578600  1.651437
B      -2.426679 -0.428913  1.265936 -0.866740 -0.678886 -0.094709
C       1.491390 -0.638902 -0.443982 -0.434351  2.205930  2.186786
```

The simplest approach is likely to expand the denominator by 3 so that it will match the dimension of the full dataframe.  Alternatively you could loop over the columns but then you have to re-combine them afterwards which may not be as easy as you'd think in the case of a multi-index.  So broadcast column 'three' like this.

```
denom = pd.concat( [df['three']]*3, axis=1 )
denom = pd.DataFrame( denom.values, columns=df.columns, index=df.index )

first        one                 two               three          
second       foo       bar       foo       bar       foo       bar
A      -0.578600  1.651437 -0.578600  1.651437 -0.578600  1.651437
B      -0.678886 -0.094709 -0.678886 -0.094709 -0.678886 -0.094709
C       2.205930  2.186786  2.205930  2.186786  2.205930  2.186786
```

The first 'denom' line just expands the 'three' column to be the same shape as the existing dataframe.  The second 'denom' is necessary to match the row and column indices.  Now you can just write a normal divide operation.

```
df / denom

first        one                 two           three    
second       foo       bar       foo       bar   foo bar
A       1.876305  0.603926 -0.489074 -0.912112     1   1
B       3.574501  4.528744 -1.864725  9.151619     1   1
C       0.676082 -0.292165 -0.201267 -0.198625     1   1
```

A quick note on the one liner relative to this longer solution.  The `values` in the one liner converts from a dataframe to an array, which has the convenient side effect of erasing the row and column indices.  Alternatively in this longer solution I explicitly conform the indices.  Depending on your situation, either approach could be a better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use `unstack()` to obtain a `pd.Series`, divide by that, and then restore the structure using `stack()`.

First I'll create an array with the same structure as your example:

```
elems = itertools.count()
df = pd.DataFrame(collections.OrderedDict(((a, b, c), {'a': next(elems), 'b': next(elems)}) for a in ['one', 'two', 'three'] for b in ['1', '2'] for c in ['X', 'Y']))
```

This gives:

```
  one          two             three
    1     2      1       2         1       2
    X  Y  X  Y   X   Y   X   Y     X   Y   X   Y
a   0  2  4  6   8  10  12  14    16  18  20  22
b   1  3  5  7   9  11  13  15    17  19  21  23
```

Then to do the division:

```
df_stacked = df.stack(level=[1, 2])
result_stacked = df_stacked.div(df_stacked['three'], axis=0)
result = result_stacked.unstack(level=[-2, -1])
```

It's necessary to reindex the result, since it seems like `unstack`/`stack` can change the ordering.

```
result = result.reindex_like(df)
```

This gives:

```
        one                                     two                               three
          1                   2                   1                   2               1         2
          X         Y         X         Y         X         Y         X         Y     X    Y    X    Y
a  0.000000  0.111111  0.200000  0.272727  0.500000  0.555556  0.600000  0.636364   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
b  0.058824  0.157895  0.238095  0.304348  0.529412  0.578947  0.619048  0.652174   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

After writing my first answer, I found a different solution using `DataFrame.align()` which is perhaps neater. This approach is described in the [official doc for multi-indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html). It's necessary to give names to the levels.

```
elems = itertools.count()
df = pd.DataFrame(collections.OrderedDict(((a, b, c), {'a': next(elems), 'b': next(elems)}) for a in ['one', 'two', 'three'] for b in ['1', '2'] for c in ['X', 'Y']))
df.columns.names = ['level0', 'level1', 'level2']
```

```
level0 one          two             three
level1   1     2      1       2         1       2
level2   X  Y  X  Y   X   Y   X   Y     X   Y   X   Y
a        0  2  4  6   8  10  12  14    16  18  20  22
b        1  3  5  7   9  11  13  15    17  19  21  23
```

Then we can simply do:

```
p, q = df.align(df['three'])
result = p / q
```

Unfortunately, it's necessary to do some re-ordering to recover the original structure:

```
result = result.reorder_levels(df.columns.names, axis=1).reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
```

This gives:

```
level0       one                                     two                               three
level1         1                   2                   1                   2               1         2
level2         X         Y         X         Y         X         Y         X         Y     X    Y    X    Y
a       0.000000  0.111111  0.200000  0.272727  0.500000  0.555556  0.600000  0.636364   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
b       0.058824  0.157895  0.238095  0.304348  0.529412  0.578947  0.619048  0.652174   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```